# Editing posts containing code

Tags: feature-request

Majority of the posts that are posted on SO contain code samples/snippets. Some of the code snippets are pretty lengthy. And users do not format the code properly. They require to be edited later like remove extra tab spaces etc.

I feel that if the edit box could have more features like selecting text vertically (using Alt + Shift keys), entering tab space when Tab key is pressed etc., it would be much easier to edit posts.

Comment: Not that I disagree...but I would imagine that to facilitate easier editing of code, one would place said code in their editor/IDE of choice and format it *there*.

Comment: @Makoto: Ya I do agree. I posted this after seeing a lot of posts which are tedious to edit.

Comment: Yeah.  I just have IntelliJ running when I feel the urge to reformat code.  Helps tons and I don't need to worry all that much about Stack Exchange implementing that feature (even though it'd be awesome).

Comment: Having richer code-editing support in the text editor would be nice, I agree.